How to navigate back to desired page in .NET MAUI using NavigationPage?
I am using .NET MAUI Navigation page for navigating between pages.
Splash Page ,
1st Page ,
2nd Page ,
3rd Page ,
4th Page ,
5th Page ,
6th Page ,
7th Page ,
8th Page ,
9th Page ,
10th Page ,
On 10th page i print the Navigation.Navigationstack.Count(); then i get 10.
now i want to navigate back to my 3rd Page directly from my 10th page .
How can i do this? If anyone knows please help .
I am trying this but it's not working.
 int page = Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList().FindIndex(p => p is Thirdpage);

  if (page >= 0)
  {
      for (int i = Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1; i > page; i--)
      {
          var pageToRemove = Navigation.NavigationStack[i];
          Navigation.RemovePage(pageToRemove);
      }

      while (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > page + 1)
      {
          await Navigation.PopAsync(false); 
      }
  }
  else
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Third Page  not found in the navigation stack!");
  }


The logic of your code is not correct, please refer to the following code:
int page = Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList().FindIndex(p => p is Thirdpage);

  if (page >= 0)
  {
      for (int i = Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1; i > page; i--)
      {
          var pageToRemove = Navigation.NavigationStack[i];
          //Navigation.RemovePage(pageToRemove);
          await Navigation.PopAsync();
      }

      //while (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > page + 1)
      //{
      //    await Navigation.PopAsync(false); 
      //}
  }
  else
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Third Page not found in the navigation stack!");
  }


This did not work as described for me. It only navigates back to the previous page;... NinthPage.

Hi @ibs mdmosabbir, could you please post  a basic demo  so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

The code you provided is close, but it has some issues. Here's a corrected version:
int pageIndex = Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList().FindIndex(p => p is ThirdPage);

if (pageIndex >= 0)
{
    while (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > pageIndex + 1)
    {
        Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Third Page not found in the navigation stack!");
}

Here's what's changed:

I removed the for loop and replaced it with a while loop. This is because we don't need to iterate over the entire navigation stack, we just need to remove pages until we reach the desired index.

I changed Navigation.PopAsync(false) to Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]). This is because PopAsync will animate the page removal, which might not be what you want. RemovePage will simply remove the page from the navigation stack without animation.

I removed the await keyword, as RemovePage is a synchronous method.
This code should work as expected. It finds the index of the ThirdPage in the navigation stack, and then removes all pages above that index, effectively navigating back to the ThirdPage.


Note that this code assumes that the ThirdPage is still in the navigation stack. If the user has navigated away from the ThirdPage and then back to the 10thPage, the ThirdPage might not be in the navigation stack anymore. In that case, you might need to recreate the ThirdPage instance and push it onto the navigation stack.

i try your code but its not working only navigating to previous page
